# CSV search and replace a specific row or column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tkinter

I was searching for a while without any Solutions for my Problem.
I hope someone could help me out a Little bit.
First of all, I am a beginner with pyhton.(3.7)

My Programm should do:
A customer comes to the Company and gets registered with Name,mail and an ID(=1)
if the customer exists already the ID should Count to 10 (ID+1)

so far it works that the customer gets added to the csv.
Missing is the part, when the customer is already in the csv.
I know that the ID is always in the same column, so i just want to replace the ID in the csv.
the CSV Looks smth like this:
Surname, Name, mail,telephonenr., ID
Max, Mustermann, max@test.com,000,1

```
    def button_action():
Vorname = eingabe_vorname.get()
Nachname = eingabe_nachname.get()
mail = eingabe_mail.get()
tel = eingabe_tel.get()
#ID = 1
if (Vorname == "" or Nachname == "" or mail == ""):
namen_label.config(text="Bitte fülle alle Felder aus.")
else:
infos=(Vorname,Nachname,mail,tel,ID)
#checks if the name is already knwown
#counts purchases until 10th, than resets the counter
with open('C:\\temp\\csv.csv') as csvfile:
list = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
for row in list:
if(len(row) > 4):
if (Vorname ==row[0] and Nachname == row[1] and mail == row[2] and tel == row[3]):
namen_label.config(text='vorhanden')
einkauf = int(row[4])
if einkauf <9:
einkauf_neu = einkauf + 1
namen_label.config(text=('Kunde bereits vorhanden, bereits der ',einkauf_neu,' Einkauf'))
else:
namen_label.config(text='Bereits der 10 Einkauf,gratis gift')
einkauf_neu = 0
new_entry = (Vorname,Nachname,mail,tel,einkauf_neu)
#overwrite of theID 
with open ('C:\\temp\\csv1.csv','w') as output_exist:
writeexist = csv.writer(output_exist)
writeexist.writerow(new_entry)#where? I want to write in the same column where the name isI tried to finish it on my own but i struggle with the replace of the ID
```

I would like to accomplish it without any extra modul like Pandas or smth like that.

If someone has a tipp for me it would be great.

Comment: You have a lot of code here. Follow the instructions on this link and please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry, i've deleted the other parts

Comment: If you working with `csv` you can't change single row. You should read whole file into the memory, change corresponding record and write all records back into the file (overwrite existing or create new).

Comment: I found this Solution aswell, but i struggle with the overwrite of that one row. Append a row or write all rows to the new csv is no Problem, but "overwrite" is my problem